# how to send images from activity to non activity class in kotlin android

Tags: kotlin, android-intent

I am facing a problem as I am very beginner in kotlin . i have a grid view activity where there are some png image . now when i click on the image i want to send this image to class a function accept drawable .upon clicking mainactivity will also open but as i have to send the images from activity to a class that is not an activity thus, i can't use intent . for that reason i first send the image via intent from grid activity to mainactivity then tried to access the image from mainactivity but non working either.

here is the gridviewactivity:

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GalleryactivityBinding binding;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = GalleryactivityBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        String[] flowerName = {"Rose", "Lotus", "Lily", "Jasmine",
                "Tulip", "Orchid", "Levender", "RoseMarry"};


        int[] flowerImages = {R.drawable.wrist, R.drawable.wrist_1, R.drawable.wrist_2, R.drawable.wrist_3, R.drawable.wrist_4, R.drawable.wrist_5, R.drawable.wrist_5_1,
                R.drawable.flower};

        Gridadapter gridAdapter = new Gridadapter(GalleryActivity.this, flowerName, flowerImages);
        binding.gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);


        binding.gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                // Get the clicked item's image resource (assuming you have an array of image resources named 'flowerImages')
                 int clickedImageResource = flowerImages[position];


                Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "You Clicked on " + flowerImages[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("clickedImageResource", clickedImageResource);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

here is the mainactivity where i sent the image via intent

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val viewModel : MainViewModel by viewModels()


    private lateinit var overlayView: OverlayView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)



            // Retrieve the extra data from the intent
            val clickedImageResource = intent.getIntExtra("clickedImageResource", 0)
            overlayView = OverlayView(this, null, clickedImageResource)
            // Use the clickedImageResource variable as needed
            // ...









        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        activityMainBinding.navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
        activityMainBinding.navigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
            // ignore the reselection
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finish()
    }
}
```

here is the non activity class from where i triend to access the image that has been sent to mainactivity

```
class OverlayView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?,private val clickedImageResource: Int) :
    View(context, attrs) {


    private var results: HandLandmarkerResult? = null
    private var linePaint = Paint()
    private var pointPaint = Paint()

    private var scaleFactor: Float = 3f
    private var imageWidth: Int = 1
    private var imageHeight: Int = 1




    // Declare the bitmaps as member variables in your class
    private  var thumbStickerBitmap: Bitmap
    private  var wristStickerBitmap: Bitmap


// Load the sticker bitmaps once, e.g., in your initialization code or constructor


    init {

        initPaints()


        thumbStickerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, clickedImageResource)
        wristStickerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.wrist_5_1)

//
//        val clickedImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, clickedImageResource)
//        thumbStickerBitmap = clickedImageBitmap
//        wristStickerBitmap = clickedImageBitmap



    }

    fun clear() {
        results = null
        linePaint.reset()
        pointPaint.reset()
        invalidate()
        initPaints()
    }

    private fun initPaints() {
        linePaint.color =
            ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.mp_color_primary)
        linePaint.strokeWidth = LANDMARK_STROKE_WIDTH
        linePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE

        pointPaint.color = Color.YELLOW
        pointPaint.strokeWidth = LANDMARK_STROKE_WIDTH
        pointPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }


    // Override the draw function
    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas)
        results?.let { handLandmarkerResult ->
            // Check if hand landmarks are detected
            if (handLandmarkerResult.landmarks().isEmpty()) {
                // No hand landmarks detected, do not proceed further
                return
            }

            // Thumb sticker transformation
            val thumbLandmarks = handLandmarkerResult.landmarks().get(0)

            // Find the bounds of the thumb landmarks
            var left = Float.MAX_VALUE
            var top = Float.MAX_VALUE
            var right = Float.MIN_VALUE
            var bottom = Float.MIN_VALUE
            for (landmark in thumbLandmarks) {
                left = min(left, landmark.x())
                top = min(top, landmark.y())
                right = max(right, landmark.x())
                bottom = max(bottom, landmark.y())
            }

            // Calculate the center coordinates of the thumb landmarks
            val centerX =
                (left + right) * 0.5f * imageWidth * scaleFactor + (imageWidth * scaleFactor * -0.03f)
            val centerY =
                (top + bottom) * 0.5f * imageHeight * scaleFactor + (imageHeight * scaleFactor * 0.02f)

            // Define the desired size of the thumb sticker
//            val desiredThumbStickerWidth = (right - left) * imageWidth * scaleFactor
//            val desiredThumbStickerHeight = (bottom - top) * imageHeight * scaleFactor

            // Define the scaling factors for the thumb sticker (smaller than 1.0 to make it smaller)
            val thumbScaleX = 0.5f
            val thumbScaleY = 0.5f
            val desiredThumbStickerWidth = (right - left) * imageWidth * scaleFactor * thumbScaleX
            val desiredThumbStickerHeight = (bottom - top) * imageHeight * scaleFactor * thumbScaleY


            // Create a new matrix for the perspective transformation of the thumb sticker
            val thumbMatrix = Matrix()

            // Set the perspective transformation points
            val thumbSrc = floatArrayOf(
                0f,
                0f,                                 // Top left
                thumbStickerBitmap.width.toFloat(),
                0f,  // Top right
                thumbStickerBitmap.width.toFloat(),
                thumbStickerBitmap.height.toFloat(),   // Bottom right
                0f,
                thumbStickerBitmap.height.toFloat()     // Bottom left
            )

            val thumbDst = floatArrayOf(
                centerX - desiredThumbStickerWidth * 0.5f,
                centerY - desiredThumbStickerHeight * 0.5f,  // Top left
                centerX + desiredThumbStickerWidth * 0.5f,
                centerY - desiredThumbStickerHeight * 0.5f,  // Top right
                centerX + desiredThumbStickerWidth * 0.5f,
                centerY + desiredThumbStickerHeight * 0.5f,  // Bottom right
                centerX - desiredThumbStickerWidth * 0.5f,
                centerY + desiredThumbStickerHeight * 0.5f   // Bottom left


            )


            // Set the scale transformation to the thumb matrix
            thumbMatrix.setScale(thumbScaleX, thumbScaleY, centerX, centerY)

            // Apply the perspective transformation to the thumb sticker bitmap
            thumbMatrix.setPolyToPoly(thumbSrc, 0, thumbDst, 0, 4)
            val transformedThumbBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                thumbStickerBitmap,
                0,
                0,
                thumbStickerBitmap.width,
                thumbStickerBitmap.height,
                thumbMatrix,
                true
            )

            // Draw the transformed thumb sticker bitmap on the canvas
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                transformedThumbBitmap,
                centerX - desiredThumbStickerWidth * 0.5f,
                centerY - desiredThumbStickerHeight * 0.5f,
                null
            )

            // Recycle the transformed thumb sticker bitmap to release memory
            transformedThumbBitmap.recycle()

            // Wrist sticker transformation
            val wristLandmarks = handLandmarkerResult.landmarks()[0]

            val normalizedLandmark = wristLandmarks.get(0)
            val wristX = normalizedLandmark.x() * imageWidth * scaleFactor
            val wristY = normalizedLandmark.y() * imageHeight * scaleFactor

            // Calculate the width and height of the wrist
            val wristWidth =
                handLandmarkerResult.landmarks()[0].get(9).x() * imageWidth * scaleFactor - wristX
            val wristHeight =
                handLandmarkerResult.landmarks()[0].get(5).y() * imageHeight * scaleFactor - wristY

            // Define the scaling factors for the wrist sticker
            val wristScaleX = 1f
            val wristScaleY = 1f

            // Create a new matrix for the scaling and perspective transformation of the wrist sticker
            val wristMatrix = Matrix()

            // Apply scaling to the wrist matrix
            wristMatrix.setScale(wristScaleX, wristScaleY)

            // Apply perspective transformation to the wrist matrix
            val wristSrc = floatArrayOf(
                0f,
                0f,  // Top left
                wristStickerBitmap.width.toFloat(),
                0f,  // Top right
                wristStickerBitmap.width.toFloat(),
                wristStickerBitmap.height.toFloat(),  // Bottom right
                0f,
                wristStickerBitmap.height.toFloat()  // Bottom left
            )

            val stickerX = wristX - wristWidth * wristScaleX * +1.15f
            val stickerY = wristY - wristHeight * wristScaleY * -0.09f

            val wristDst = floatArrayOf(
                stickerX,
                stickerY + wristHeight * wristScaleY,  // Top left
                stickerX + wristWidth * wristScaleX,
                stickerY + wristHeight * wristScaleY,  // Top right
                stickerX + wristWidth * wristScaleX,
                stickerY,  // Bottom right
                stickerX,
                stickerY   // Bottom left
            )
            wristMatrix.setPolyToPoly(wristSrc, 0, wristDst, 0, 4)

            // Apply the transformation matrix to the wrist sticker bitmap
            val transformedWristBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                wristStickerBitmap,
                0,
                0,
                wristStickerBitmap.width,
                wristStickerBitmap.height,
                wristMatrix,
                true
            )

            // Draw the transformed wrist sticker bitmap on the canvas
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                transformedWristBitmap,
                stickerX,
                stickerY,
                null
            )

            // Recycle the transformed wrist sticker bitmap to release memory
            transformedWristBitmap.recycle()
        }
    }


    fun setResults(
        handLandmarkerResults: HandLandmarkerResult,
        imageHeight: Int,
        imageWidth: Int,
        runningMode: RunningMode = RunningMode.IMAGE
    ) {
        results = handLandmarkerResults

        this.imageHeight = imageHeight
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth

        scaleFactor = when (runningMode) {
            RunningMode.IMAGE,
            RunningMode.VIDEO -> {
                min(width * 1f / imageWidth, height * 1f / imageHeight)
            }
            RunningMode.LIVE_STREAM -> {
                // PreviewView is in FILL_START mode. So we need to scale up the
                // landmarks to match with the size that the captured images will be
                // displayed.
                max(width * 1f / imageWidth, height * 1f / imageHeight)
            }
        }
        invalidate()
    }


    companion object {
        private const val LANDMARK_STROKE_WIDTH = 8F
    }
}
```

help me fix this . i have tried so many as a begginer did not figure